# my magento site suddenly gives this error can anyone help me out?

Tags: error, xml

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 14: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: layout line 2 and arithmetic_integer_multiply  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/html/a...', 444, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(444): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'smartwave', 'custom', '1')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'porto_home_11')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'porto_home_11')
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/local/NextBits/Marketplace/Controller/Router/Vendor.php(39): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): NextBits_Marketplace_Controller_Router_Vendor->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages is telling you the problem:

Go to this file

```
/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
```

And before the line 440 add this:

```
die(print_r($filename, true)); // ADD THIS LINE
$filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
    '_area'    => $area,
    '_package' => $package,
    '_theme'   => $theme
));
```

Have you modify any layout.xml, config.xml or any other .xml file? Have you recently installed any extension?

If so, then check the files you modify apparently there is a mismatching tag, most likely you forgot the closing node.

If you recently installed an extension start by disabling it and check if it works after that.

**Remember to flush the cache after every change.**

Comment: Thanks for replying....and i have solved that issue..but i have another question i.e. if i have to add  a new page in magento to customize with my php codes tofetch details form database so what steps should i have to follow

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in one of your installed extensions is an xml "bad written".

Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842275/magento-simplexml-load-string-error-location and give it a try.

Good luck !